# What OS commands are needed to control USB?

Tags: io, operating-system, windows-10, usb, fpga

I am a college undergrad studying computer engineering and trying to send signals using USB to an FPGA from a windows computer connected to the FPGA using usb. What commands can i use to output/input data from my computer?
For background:
I am working on a windows 10 laptop. I am using python currently to run a program that gets the data from the user. The data is literally just a set of binary bits (up to about 75 bits), our project is to do with encoding, so our fpga is supposed to take the data then encode it using block codes, then send the data back, then the data is to be slightly corrupted, sent back to the FPGA, then error checked and decoded and sent to the computer again. The FPGA we have is a Cyclone 5 (Model Number: 5csema5f31c6).
I have recently started taking an OS class and since the OS controls how hardware is used by programs, i assume my programs will need to issue certain commands to the OS which will then tell the USB to do what we want.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what specific driver you are using to talk to your device.  If your device is just a generic USB device and doesn't fit into an existing category (like a keyboard or printer), then I'd recommend using the driver named [WinUSB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/winusb).

You would need to write (and sign) an INF file or use a technology called Microsoft OS 2.0 Descriptors to tell Windows that you want your device to use WinUSB.

After you've done that, you can use a Microsoft-provided DLL called winusb.dll which helps you send the commands that the WinUSB driver expects.  You'd also need to use SetupAPI to find your device in the first place.  Using those two Microsoft APIs directly can be difficult and it makes your code non-portable, so you might consider using a USB abstraction library like [libusb](https://libusb.info/) or [libusbp](https://github.com/pololu/libusbp) instead.